# project qgis 2.14 empty

Tags: qgis, qgs

I encounter the problem more and more often and it begins seriously to become embarrassing :
I open a project of yesterday and it is empty or I just have the title groups, groups emptied of their layers.
And the layers of the project are shp and virtual layers resulting from queries.
So 
The .qgs has hundreds of kilos and when I edit it, I find my layers in the  tags, the paths are good, I have no messages like what tags are badly closed and file is not truncated.
Is project finally lost ?

Comment: some question which pops into my mind: do you have the newest qgis installation? Can you reproduce the error when you save it as a new project file? does the error occur only when you shut down the pc?

Comment: If you rename your `project.qgs~` to `somethingelse.qgs`, can you open that?

Comment: I tried with Qgis 2.18 : same result ; I can't reproduce the error ; for the third question : I don't know, actually I am using stand-by mode.

Comment: Opening the second project with a new name does not work either.

Comment: Try  uninstalling all your plugins - maybe there's an offending plugin which is corrupting the projects

Comment: I only have left native plugins such gdalgeoreferencer or processing. No effect.

Comment: The project has a dozen of virtual layers. Two of them make the project crash. When removed it is ok.